# Gentoo emerge from a list with USE flags and specific version

Tags: gentoo

I've got a list of packages from a Gentoo server, like that:

```
[...snip...]
media-libs/libsdl-1.2.13 -X -aalib -alsa -arts -custom-cflags -dga -directfb -esd -fbcon -ggi -libcaca -nas -noaudio -nojoystick -novideo -opengl -oss -pulseaudio -svga -xinerama -xv
media-libs/libsndfile-1.0.17-r1 -alsa -flac -sqlite
media-libs/libtheora-1.0_beta3-r1 -doc -encode -examples
media-libs/libvorbis-1.2.1_rc1 -doc
media-libs/t1lib-5.0.2 -X -doc
media-libs/tiff-3.8.2-r2 +zlib -jbig -jpeg -nocxx
media-libs/win32codecs-20071007-r2 -real
media-libs/x264-0.0.20070924 -debug -threads
media-libs/xvid-1.1.3 -altivec -examples
media-sound/lame-3.98.2 -debug -mmx -mp3rtp -sndfile
media-sound/twolame-0.3.12
media-tv/linuxtv-dvb-headers-3.1
media-video/ffmpeg-0.4.9_p20070616-r3 +a52 +aac +amr +encode +ogg +sdl +theora +truetype +v4l +vorbis +x264 +xvid +zlib -X -altivec -debug -doc -ieee1394 -imlib -mmx -network -oss -test -threads
media-video/mpeg2vidcodec-12-r1
media-video/mplayer-1.0_rc2_p24929-r4 +a52 +aac +aalib +amrnb +amrwb +dvb +encode +ftp +iconv +kernel_linux +mp2 +mp3 +sdl +teletext +theora +truetype +unicode +v4l +v4l2 +video_cards_mga +video_cards_s3virge +video_cards_tdfx +video_cards_vesa +vorbis +win32codecs +x264 +xanim +xvid -3dnow -3dnowext -X -alsa -altivec -arts -bidi -bindist -bl -cddb -cdio -cdparanoia -cpudetection -custom-cflags -debug -dga -directfb -doc -dts -dv -dvd -enca -esd -fbcon -ggi -gif -gtk -ipv6 -jack -joystick -jpeg -ladspa -libcaca -lirc -live -livecd -lzo -mad -md5sum -mmx -mmxext -musepack -nas -nemesi -openal -opengl -oss -png -pnm -pulseaudio -quicktime -radio -rar -real -rtc -samba -speex -srt -sse -sse2 -ssse3 -svga -tga -tivo -vidix -xinerama -xv -xvmc -zoran
media-video/xanim-2.80.1-r4
[...snip...]
```

And I want to install them on a another gentoo server (fresh install).
The problem is I want to be sure to have the exact same version of software and exact same flags.

I've search on google, try to set /etc/portage/package.use and package.accept_keywords according to information I got on this list but it did'nt succeed.

Some can help me please? Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 1):

Would it be useful for you to use **quickpkg** to create binary packages from existing system and then deploy those to your new server with **emerge -k**?

Comment: Hi, I'd like to but I don't have any more access to my "source" server. Moreover when I got access I haven't a root access but just a regular user. It's not a problem if the rebuild take a long time.

Answer (score 1):

What did you try? Given, e.g.,

```
media-libs/tiff-3.8.2-r2 +zlib -jbig -jpeg -nocxx
```

you'd put

```
media-libs/tiff zlib -jbig -jpeg -nocxx
```

in `/etc/portage/package.use`--note lack of version number and no `+`-- and

```
>media-libs/tiff-3.8.2-r2
<media-libs/tiff-3.8.2-r2
```

in `/etc/portage/package.mask`.

Answer (score 0):

When you say it didn't succeed, I could imagine that the problem you are having might be that the portage tree the old server was using is a lot older than the one you are using now, and a number of the old versions of software have meanwhile been dropped from the tree.

E.g. the first ebuild in your list, media-libs/libsdl-1.2.13, isn't in my portage tree any more.

If you really need the exactly same versions, you also need a portage tree from the time these ebuilds were installed.

I've never done that, but one way to get such a tree might be to check it out from CVS, for the respective date.
Portage CVS is located at http://sources.gentoo.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/gentoo-x86/

Should this install complete, I'd recommend to update the portage tree and check for security updates.
Then you can decide which exact versions you want to keep.